# 404 error when testing on fiddler/postman

Tags: iis

I have a Web project using .net framework 4.5 and testing it using IIS Express(7.0) locally looks like something is wrong with my local configuration.

I tried adding code in web config as suggested in other's post but that didn't work for me.

tried adding "
      
      
    "
also tried runAllManagedModulesForAllRequest=true

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I tried following code in web config  in modules     
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>

Comment: You should provide more debugging information such as output console log from Visual Studio. Some part of code (incriminated controller, route configuration, ...) might be helpful. In addition are you explicitly setting Accept Header when writing your requests with fiddler?

Comment: No, I am not setting Accept header in fiddler. Code for controller is simple - [HttpPost]
        [Route("olicies")] 
        public IHttpActionResult Olicy(OViewModel model)
        {
            return this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

Comment: For post request Content-Type must be set and Accept header should be set as well. I personally faced issues of the sort when not properly setting those headers [further reading on the matter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation). We definitely need more information to further help you (fiddler detailed trace, output log, trace, code etc...)

Comment: Thanks Cyprien.. I got it working now. It turned out to be permission problem.